# Javascript Access inner object parameter

Tags: javascript

say I have a dict like this:

```
colors = {
  green: {
    light: "lightgreen",
    dark: "darkgreen",
  },
  blue: {
    light: "lightblue",
    dark: "darkblue",
  }
}
```

How can I index into this with ***ONE key***, like `"green.light"`. I tried `colors["green.light"]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `colors["green"]["light"]` or `colors.green.light`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Thanks, but the point is that I want it to only be ONE key.

Comment: Check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path) question, its similar to yours

Comment: You can use `eval('colors.green.light')` if you sure the input is trustworthy

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it certain ways which are shown below, also you can write a function and define your own way like I shown below. Hope this helps

```js
colors = {
  green: {
    light: "lightgreen",
    dark: "darkgreen",
  },
  blue: {
    light: "lightblue",
    dark: "darkblue",
  }
}
// -- by defining your custom way
console.log(resolvePath(colors, "blue.light"));


function resolvePath (object, path) {
  return path
   .split('.')
   .reduce((o, p) => o ? o[p] : '', object)
 }
// -- by defining your custom way

// -- other ways below

console.log(colors["green"]["light"]);
console.log(colors.green.light);
console.log(colors["green"].light);
console.log(colors.green["light"]);
console.log(colors.green["light"]);
console.log(eval('colors.green.light')); // Thanks to @HaoWu comment, added this
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
colors = {
  green: {
    light: "lightgreen",
    dark: "darkgreen",
  },
  blue: {
    light: "lightblue",
    dark: "darkblue",
  }
}

console.log(colors.green['light'])
```